# Swapping this click function to a select list function

Tags: jquery

There's a lot of other stuff going on, but I have this working code which uses a click function on two divs which does a bunch of other stuff, like this:

```
<div id="Single">Single</div><div id="Regular">Regular</div>
```

Here's the function:

```
$(document).on('click', '#Single , #Regular', singleToDDSwitch);
```

I need to keep the same functionality but use a select list as the trigger instead. Here's the example select list:

```
<select><option id='Single'>Single</option><option id='Regular'>Regular</option></select>
```

Can anyone help, I'm not that hot at jQuery?

Comment: Did you try anything? Maybe reading some relevant material?

Comment: just a suggestion . instead of `click` use `change`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#sel', function() {
    alert($(this).find(":selected").text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
  <option>Single</option>
  <option>Regular</option>
</select>
```

In select you dont neet the individual ids.

Comment: You simply do $(this).text() instead of $(this).find(":selected").text()

Comment: Nope. Then it prints both the options. Find is for it to print the selected one. @DinoMyte

Comment: @DinoMyte Yes we can do that too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.change` event on the `<select>` element.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't really answer the question... maybe an example would be more helpful?

Comment: `.change()` doesn't bind to dynamic elements ....  Surely you mean `.on('change')`

Comment: $( "select" ).change(function() {
  alert( "A change has occured" );
});

Comment: Go ahead and try that with a dynamically created element .. Your method will not work.   Do some research on a .click()/.change  .... etc vs  .on('click')/.on('change')  ..  There is also a place for .live() (depricated in 1.7) over a strict .change() binding ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements

Comment: Thanks, will investigate further.

Comment: @Zak - technically the question didn't mention that it was dynamically created element so his approach is valid for the scenario. Neither is specifically better than the other depending on your requirements; delegated event handlers cost you at the time of triggering, direct event handlers cost you at the time of binding...